# CountIF/CountA using Array Functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a list of projects in various countries (each row is a distinct project; countries are listed in Column A). Each project can have multiple tags (e.g., demand, pedagogy, ICT, etc.). For a much larger group of projects, I am trying to fill in the table on the right in the image, so am trying to generate a count (for a map graphic) that tells me

- how many "demand" projects are in India (answer = 1),
- how many "Private" projects are in India (answer = 1),
- how many "vocational" projects are in India (answer = 4)
- etc.,
- how many "pedagogy" projects there are in Chile (answer = 0).

So am looking for a function that I can insert into each cell of the table on the right that says: for each project in country x, count if that project matches "demand" (or "ICT")... I've tried playing around with array count functions with no luck...

[image: Example data]

Comment: what have you tried and why that didn't work? Probably you will need to use `COUNTIF` for each Tag column and just sum them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` to calculate it:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A2:$A5=$E2)*(($B2:$B5=F$1)+($C2:$C5=F$1)))`

[image]